# Menu bar appearing behind iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a site with a menu bar. This is its CSS:

```
navigation {
position: relative;
z-index: 200;
}
```

In one of the pages, I have a button which triggers an `iframe` and that button is wrapped with div. The iframe is external and my div is coming over that `iframe`. I want it to be go behind, but can't seem to find a way.

I also want to make sure that any change will not impact other browsers and screen layouts (like mobile).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the z-index of the button to be less than that of the iFrame

Mess around with z-index on here:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_zindex

Comment: but iframe is triggered when button is cliked and it is triggered using a script which connects it to third party